# change include header file with regular expression

Tags: regex, sed

I changed file names, so I have to change included file names.
For example, I change alpha.h to fix_alpha.h. So I have to change 
`#include "alpha.h"`
to
`#include "fix_alpha.h"`
but there are so many files to fix like beta.h to fix_beta.h
I tried to use reg exp to fix it

```
grep -rl '*' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/*\.h``/fix_*\.h/g'
```

but it doesn't work. 
How should I wirte the reg exp to make it work?

Comment: `find . -name '*.h' -print0 | xargs -r0n 1 sed -e 's|"alpha.h"|"fix_alpha.h"|g;' -i`

Comment: are you trying to change the file name or content?

Comment: Note that your question is not really about C; you show no signs of wanting to write a C program that will do the regex mapping (probably a good thing — you'd be emulating `sed`).  I've retagged it with `sed` — you might add `grep` and `xargs` though they are not really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `grep` command looks for files containing a `*` (and most of your C files will probably have at least one comment, so all C files — source and header — will be selected).  You can do better than that, though.  For example, assuming that the names that need to be mapped are `alpha.h`, `beta.h`, `gamma.h`, and `delta.h`, and that you're a regular sane programmer who doesn't put spaces or newlines in either file names or directory names, then you can generate the list of interesting files with:

```
grep -rlE '^#include[[:space:]]*"(alpha|beta|gamma|delta)\.h"' .
```

Then, for each such file, you need to replace those header names with the `fix_` prefix.  Now you get to work out whether your `sed` has extended regular expressions.  Assuming not, then you can create a `sed` script to do the mapping for you.  For example, create a text file `mapped-headers` containing:

```
alpha.h
beta.h
gamma.h
delta.h
```

Now make that into a `sed` script with (of course) `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/\.h/\\.h/' \
    -e 's%.*%s/^#include[[:space:]]*"&"/#include "fix_&"/' \
    mapped-headers > script.sed
```

Now you can apply that script to the files containing any of the headers to be mapped using:

```
grep -rlE '^#include[[:space:]]*"(alpha|beta|gamma|delta)\.h"' . |
xargs sed -i.bak -f script.sed
```

(If you're overwriting files on Mac OS X with the `-i` option, you must provide a backup suffix, which can be attached to the `-i` option as shown, or in a separate option; if you want no suffix but overwriting, you have to write `-i ''` on Mac.  By contrast, if you're using GNU `sed`, the backup suffix is optional, but if present, it must be attached to the `-i` option.  What's shown will work on both platforms.  Not all versions of `sed` support the `-i` option for overwriting.)

The extension to 100 headers with the simple prefix mapping should be obvious, at least for the `sed` script part.  You could also have a `sed` script generate the `grep` script too; it would be similar in spirit, but simpler than the one shown.

You can write fancier regular expressions to match deviant layouts for the `#include` directives.  You might allow for spaces before the `#`, and after the `#`.  If you have comments in the operational part of your `#include` lines, you've got bigger problems than just mapping the names.  This code won't handle:

```
/* comments? */    #    \
include /*
    */   "alpha.h"
```

But no-one who's sane writes code like that anyway.

Further, if you have some not wholly systematic renamings to do, you can revise the script to handle that by changing the `mapped-headers` file to have the 'old' and 'new' values in separate columns:

```
alpha.h    alphabet.h
beta.h     veg/carotene.h
gamma.h    hard/radiation.h
delta.h    v-wing.h
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find -name '*.h' -exec sed -i 's~alpha.h~fix_alpha.h~' {} \;
```

Your code may contains `/`,so here use `~` delimiter

Comment: The appearances of the headers in source files need to be fixed too; this only looks for header files and assumes that each header includes the target header.

Comment: If neither the search regex nor the replacement string contain a slash, you could certainly still use a slash delimiter. The choice of delimiter is completely arbitrary so `~` is perfectly fine as well, of course.

Answer (score 0):

How's is it not working? 
Anyway, your regex seems not making sense to me.  I believe you could simply replace by

```
sed 's|^\(\s*#\s*include\s.*[*/"]\)\([^/"]*\)\.h\(".*\)$|\1fix_\2.h\3|'
       \                          / \       /    \     /
           lines start with          header      everything
           #include, match           filename    after .h
           until the " or / 
           before the header 
           filename
```

Example:

```
#include "foo.h"
# include "foo.h"
   #  include "foo.h"
#include "foo/bar.h"
#include "foo/bar.h"    // something else
```

result

```
#include "fix_foo.h"
# include "fix_foo.h"
   #  include "fix_foo.h"
#include "foo/fix_bar.h"
#include "foo/fix_bar.h"    // something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
find . -type f -print | xargs sed -i 's/#include "/&fix_/'
```